# Proving equation has only one solution

Tags: calculus

So i want to prove that
$$x^2e^x=1$$ has at least one solution for $$x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I am kinda lost and would appreciate any help. This is suppose to be solved using basic  calculus but i am not sure what to use.

Comment: Are you familiar with Intermediate value theorem?

Comment: I am but i am not sure how to use it here

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^2e^x-1$. What can you say?

Comment: Not really sure, should i find an interval and then use the theorem?

Comment: Yes, you may notice that $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$. Can you continue?

Comment: @Galc127 Note that this approach will give existence but not uniqueness (at least not in its current form).

Comment: And then because its continous on [0,1] and f(0) <0 and f(1)>0 then there is such $$x\in[0,1]$$ that f(x)=0?

Comment: Also i don't need uniqueness,just need to prove existance of at least one

Comment: @πr8, I know it gives only existence, didn't want to give full solution.
user, you need to show uniqueness as you are required to show there is only one solution.

Comment: Thats my mistake now,i made a typo.

Comment: Was just need to prove existance of at least one.

Comment: @user246608, regardless of your typo, you can show uniqueness. Do you know how? If not, you might look at the answers, a full solution is provided.

Comment: @AlexPeter, no one asks to find the value of $x$, only to show there is such $x$. Indeed, we need Lambert W function to find the value of $x$, but this is definitely not required. Basic calculus (IVT) is enough.

Comment: @Galc127 Apologies - the initial phrasing of the question was only asking for uniqueness, so I was surprised that you hadn't addressed it.

Comment: @user246608 why did you edit the question? The uniqueness actually holds.

Comment: Because it wasnt what i was going for,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to sketch a graph of $y=x^2 e^x$, paying particular attention to any minima and maxima it may have. Once you've done this, superimpose $y=1$ onto this graph to see what any solutions might look like.

1) **Existence**

If $f(x)=x^2e^x$, then

- $f$ is continuous
- $f(0)=0<1<e=f(1)$

By the intermediate value theorem, there exists a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=1$, i.e. $c^2e^c=1$

2) **Uniqueness**

Using well-known inequality $e^y\ge1+y$ with $y=-1-\frac{x}{2}$, we see:

$$e^{-1-\frac{x}{2}}\ge -\frac{x}{2}\implies\frac{2}{e}\ge -xe^{x/2}\implies x^2e^x\le\frac{4}{e^2}<1\text{ for }x<0$$

and this tells us that $x^2e^x$ will have no solutions for negative $x$.

For positive $x$, $x^2e^x$ is monotonically increasing ($x^2,e^x$ are both positive and increasing, thus their product also is), so the positive solution $c$ we found earlier must be the only solution, and we thus have uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Call $f(x)=x^2 e^x -1$, and note that it is continuous. Since
$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2 e^x -1) = e^x(x^2+2x)$$

we have that $(0,-1)$ is a maximum and $(-2,4e^{-2}-1)$ is a minimum.

Since $4e^{-2}-1<0$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=-1$  we know that $f$ is negative in $(-\infty, -2)$. We also know that it is decreasing in $(-2,0)$, so still negative.

The function is strictly increasing in $(0, \infty)$ and since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ it has to cross the $x$ axis once (and only once) in that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Since the statement is always positive $x^2$ is positive $e^x$ is positive we can take the logarithm and have more tangible:

$$x+2\log(|x|)=0$$

Now we have $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x+2\log(|x|)=-\infty$. Observe that this is so for both sides of $0$: $0^{+}$ and $0^{-}$. So we are interested what is happening with the function once it leaves $0$.

Notice:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x+2\log(|x|)=+\infty$$

so there has to be at least one zero from $0$ to $+\infty$.

If we take first derivative of $f(x)=x+2\log(|x|)$ we have $f'(x)=\frac{x+2}{x}$

There is one zero of the first derivative at $x=-2$ for which $f(-2)=-2+2\log(2)<0$. This means that we cannot have zero in the region $x < 0$ since we would have to have at least one more minima/maxima somewhere within $x < 0$ and we do not.

For $x>0$ the expression $\frac{x+2}{x}$ is always positive, so the function is raising all the time from $-\infty$, and since it goes to $+\infty$ and the function has no other discontinuity except at $0$, we cannot have more than one value for which $f(x)=0$.